# Miscoservice can't connect to docker posgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker-compose

In my microservice i connected to MySQL database, but i decided to connect to PostgreSQL using docker container.
PostgreSQL docker-compose:

```
  #Postgres Configuration
  postgres-order:
    container_name: postgres-order
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: order-service
      POSTGRES_USER: matvey
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: matvey
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres-order:/data/postgres
    expose:
      - "5431"
    ports:
      - "5431:5431"
    command: -p 5431
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This is my service docker-compose:

```
  #Order Service
  order-service:
    container_name: order-service
    image: zaxarleningod/order-service
    pull_policy: always
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-order:5431/order-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-order
      - broker
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
```

And this is configuration in properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-order:5431/order-service
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=matvey
spring.datasource.password=matvey
```

After that i run docker compose and get error in order-service container:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to postgres-order:5431 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

It is weird but i see that hostname and port are correct, where can be a problem?

Comment: If you run it locally, should not it be localhost:5431 rather then postgres-order:5431?

Answer (score 0):

I think your option: `command: -p 5431` is not correctly, try it by **comment or remove** this line, then restart your docker-compose

```
docker-compose up
```